# Switched from Windows XP to Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows, performance, migration

I have a computer, below are the specs:

RAM: 1GB DDR2
Processor: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 2.53GHz
Network Adapter: Intel(R) PRO/100 VE Network Connection (Ethernet)
500GB IDE HDD

The computer is currently running Windows XP and is extremely slow, is switching to Ubuntu 12.04LTS a good idea (performance wise)?

Thank you :)

Comment: 12.04 using unity runs like a kitten on my p4 and p4x2 with similar amount of available ram.  2GB would be better...  Upgrade to Ubuntu and see. You can try without installing.

Comment: I would install Lubuntu since you only have 1GB of RAM. it's not that much...

Answer (score 5):

Because of possible performance issues you should choose Xubuntu 12.04 32-bit. Xubuntu 12.04 is a Long Term Support release (LTS) that is supported by updates until April, 2015 (Update: the latest LTS release is 14.04). Lubuntu is also an option, but it does not yet have Long Term Support. However Lubuntu 14.04 will be an LTS release which will be supported by updates for three years until April, 2017.

Comment: Lubuntu 14.04 will be an LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, but I would recommend you to choose lightweight window managers like lxde, openbox, xfce instead of gnome/kde/unity.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your specs you may not experience performance issues as in Ubuntu's official site states that; A good "rule of thumb" is that machines that could run XP, Vista, Windows 7 or x86 OS X will almost always be a lot faster with Ubuntu even if they are lower-spec than described in [**Recommended Minimum System Requirements**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Recommended_Minimum_System_Requirements).

Simply try Ubuntu CD as a LiveCD first to check the hardware works. In such case, I would recommend you to have a look at Ubuntu's [**official documentation**](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/minimum-hardware-reqts.html) about various distribution and its useful information.

Comment: That page is old, however, and does mention that you should have _at least_ 1GB RAM when using Unity.

Comment: My bad that I didn't notice the date eventually replying for this and noticed that it was an old topic I've answered.

Answer (score 1):

As my personal experience Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is heavier than windows XP. If you are having extremely slow conditions under XP then Ubuntu 12.04 would not be a good choice given that your computer configuration is also not quite sufficient for Ubuntu 12.04 specially the RAM;
As others said go for light versions like Lubuntu or Xubuntu;

Answer (score 1):

12.04 may run well in 2D mode (you can choose it at log in).  I found that Ubuntu in 2D mode takes about the same amount of resources than Xubuntu, so try 2D first.  If that doesn't run fast enough then Lubuntu is a good choice for the amount of RAM you have installed.

I expect your WinXP installation is running slow due to fragmentation issues, or various mal-ware finding it's way on your system.  You might be able to reinstall XP and regain your speed, but it's end of life will give you more problems than switching your operating system.